# Dimensionality reduction with PCA limitations

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, pca

What are the cases when we should not use PCA for dimensionality reduction and what to use in such cases?

Comment: Use PCA when it gets better results, or for visualizations..

Answer (score 2):

You should not use PCA if you only have categorical variables, and thus the distance function in PCA is invalid.

[Correspondence analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_analysis) is a common alternative.

Answer (score 2):

PCA is a linear transformation of your variables to a set of uncorrelated ones.

It is good when you want to remove redundancy (in a linear sense) in your data but it is bad if you want to uncover the "true cause" of the variables. Furthermore the causes can be non-linear in nature and the behavior of your data cannot be captured using a linear model.

Then you would stay away from PCA and consider e.g. [non linear dimensionality reduction methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction)